# No source available for the current location VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a whole series of dll's added into my assembly. However I cannot find a way to get past the problems of requiring the source code - which I do not have. I'm running in debug mode and the project builds and runs fie, but when using F11 to debug from a break point, when going into a method in one of these dll's I end up with this issue and I cannot make is resolve.

I have tried the following:

- Switching off address-level debugging
- Enable just my code

I really don't know what I should be doing. Any ideas?

Comment: did you copy the pdb files, too?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Are you trying to debug those DLLs?

Comment: Just move your finger over by one key and keep it there for a while.  Always use the debugger's StepOver command.  Only use StepInto when you need to debug the called method.  Which of course is pointless if you don't have source.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I thought there was an option to use F11, I guess F10 will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I thought that I could use an option in settings and continue to use F11, but it looks like I'll have to use F10 now which works fine. Thanks to @Hans Passant for his comment.